# Behavior of variables using su in linux

Tags: linux, python-poetry, su

I'm installing Poetry in a dockerfile, but I want to do it under a different user (to play nicely with VSCode). I don't understand the behavior of the `su` command though.

When I run `su vscode -c "echo $HOME"` I get `/root`. However, when I run `su vscode`, and subsequently run `echo $HOME`, I get /home/vscode`.

Even stranger, when I run `su vscode -c "echo $HOME && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3"`, I get `/root` as output of the first command, but poetry is installed to `/home/vscode/.local/bin`. I'm at a loss here... can someone shine some light on this?

Comment: We have a bunch of similar questions in the knowledge base from people trying to run commands over ssh, but using double quotes and so getting values expanded locally instead of remotely; it's all the same underlying issue (of content being expanded by your current shell when you want it to instead be expanded by a different shell that's started later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"echo $HOME"` is evaluated by your current shell *before* `su` is executed. So `su` will only be passed as argument `"echo /root"` (already-evaluated). If you want the variable to be evaluated by the shell spawned by su, you need to escape it: `'echo $HOME'`

See [2.2 Quoting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02) in the POSIX specification